# Stop application after set time - sleep timer

Tags: applications, automation

Is there a way to automatically stop playing music/stop other app after a set period of time. For instance while listening to music at night.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Music Off, I'm Sleeping!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=asia.utopia.musicoff) - seems to do what you're looking for.